# 'destroy' if the Bootstrap .popover() be on('hidden.bs.popover', is triggering another 'hidden.bs.popover' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to `'destroy'` the `.popover()` if it become `.on('hidden.bs.popover'` after it be `.on('shown.bs.popover'` so it will not `'show'` again. Everything seems right but look at the console, the event `'hidden.bs.popover'` is triggering twice because destroying a popover will trigger another `'hidden.bs.popover'` caused to destroy the destroyed popover and looks like it will affect a little of performance.

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
  $(this).popover('destroy');
  console.debug("'hidden.bs.popover' triggering twice!");
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I'd tried to figure it out but I choose not to include that for avoiding confusion. What is the right way to destroy the popover that have dismissed without triggering the same event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `one` to only bind once the event, but I believe it will work only for the first popover and then it will unbind the event from all other popovers, but it's worth giving it a chance:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').one('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
  $(this).popover('destroy');
  console.debug("'hidden.bs.popover' triggering twice!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

testing this code 
Click me

```
 $('.pop').popover();
$('.pop').on('mouseout',function(){
    $(this).popover('hide');
})
```